# AngularJS ng-repeat not binding next value for expressions that used in attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);
    app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.tests = [
            {
                id: '1',
                name: 'Test 1',
                count: '10',
                children: [{
                    name: 'Test Child 1'
                }]
            },
            {
                id: '2',
                name: 'Test 2',
                count: '19',
                children: [{
                    name: 'Test Child 2'
                }]
            },
            {
                id: '3',
                name: 'Test 3',
                count: '18',
                children: [{
                    name: 'Test Child 3'
                }]
            }
        ];
    });

    function test() {
        alert($('#testtest').attr('href'));
    }
</script>
<div ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix" ng-repeat="test in tests">
            <a id="testtest" data-toggle="collapse" href="#div_{{test.id}}" onclick="test();" class="pull-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px;">{{test.id + ' ' + test.name}} <span class="badge">{{test.count}}</span></a>
        </div>
        <div id="div_{{test.id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table id="tbl_{{test.id}}" class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Name</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="child in test.children">
                            <td>{{child.name}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to create a list of panels, with tables in it.

The outcome is:
[image]

When I click the name of the panel, it was suppose to expand the panel body, but the panel body wasn't expanding. So I alert() the`href="#div_{{test.id}}"`it showed #div_1 for all three items.

It is suppose to be #div_1, #div_2 and #div_3 just like the 1,2 and 3 number generated on the panel header.

What is my mistake?

P/s: Sorry for the bad explaination

Answer (score 1):

You are ng-repeating only the headers, you need to do it for the panels too, please try this out and let me know:

```
<div ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix" ng-repeat="test in tests">
            <a id="testtest" data-toggle="collapse" href="#div_{{test.id}}" onclick="test();" class="pull-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px;">{{test.id + ' ' + test.name}} <span class="badge">{{test.count}}</span></a>
        </div>
        <div id="div_{{test.id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse"  ng-repeat="test in tests">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table id="tbl_{{test.id}}" class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Name</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="child in test.children">
                            <td>{{child.name}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Malkus and Fedaykin both pointed out the important concept of development using AngularJS. My answer is just a wrap of these two. I have made a [working example](http://codepen.io/shaohaolin/pen/xZqvWz?editors=101) here.

Changes that I made:

```
<a id="testtest" data-toggle="collapse" ng-href="#div_{{test.id}}"
       class="pull-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px;" ng-click="selectTest(test)">
   {{test.id + ' ' + test.name}}<span class="badge">{{test.count}}</span>
</a>
```

As you can see, I have used `ng-click` to pass the select test object to the controller and `console.log(test)`. You will be able to see the object in the console.

```
$scope.selectTest = function(test) {
    console.log(test);
    $scope.selectedTest = test;
}
```

This approach allows you to have the whole object and modify it.

Another change I made is:

```
<div class="panel-collapse collapse" ng-attr-id="div_{{test.id}}" 
     ng-repeat="test in tests">
     ...
</div>
```

As **Fedaykin** mentioned, you only `ng-repeat` the panel header, which means the scope of `test` is only in the header. You are not able to access the `test` out of the header, because it is **out of scope**. Therefor you have to do another `ng-repeat` on the panel body.

I don't like this approach because it gives you less control what it has to display. And when you are encountering a giant data, you don't want to render all the data to front-end because it will cause latency and etc. So, the best approach is display the selected data when users click the corresponding panel.

#### Suggestion

Try to using `ng-click` with `ng-show`, `ng-hide`, `ng-if` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

### I see a few things that are giving you trouble:

You want to use `ng-href` hence the errors with the alerts. Also you should use `ng-click` not `onclick`

```
 <a id="testtest" data-toggle="collapse" ng-href="#div_{{test.id}}"     
     ng-click="test();" class="pull-left" style="padding-top: 7.5px;">
            {{test.id + ' ' + test.name}} 
     <span class="badge">{{test.count}}</span></a>
```

For the panels that aren't exanding `ng-repeat` only repeats the element and its contents. The section below starts after the `ng-repeat` ends.  You should also use `ng-attr-id` to update the ID with a value from the scope

```
 <div ng-attr-id="div_{{test.id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

---

#### A good rule of thumb with angular:

any time you want to use something from the scope to update an `element` or `element attribute` see if angular has a directive to manage it.  AngularJS compiles the DOM you should not be accessing or manipulating elements without a directive, in this case `ng-href`, `ng-click` and `ng-attr-id`